# DateTime get day of year

Tags: c#

I want my new year to start at `14 March`. Given any `DateTime` I want to get the day of year? How can I accomplish this with DateTime?

March 14 is the 73rd day of the year (74th in leap years) in the Gregorian calendar. 292 days remain until the end of the year. Is there a way I can define the new year of a year with `DateTime`?

Comment: [Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar) is an abstract Class: you can derived from it your own Calendar (overriding a number of virtual methods).

Comment: Otherwise, if you don't want any degree of *complexity*, you can just sum and subtract: e.g., DateTime ± TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
int DayOfYear(DateTime date, int yearStartMonth, int yearStartDay)
{
    var yearStart = new DateTime(d.Year, yearStartMonth, yearStartDay);
    if(yearStart > d)
        yearStart = yearStart.AddYears(-1);
    return (d - yearStart).Days + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
public static int DayOfYear(DateTime date)
    {
        var startDate= new DateTime(year:date.Year,month:3,day:14); //14 March 
        var diffDateDays=(date- startDate).Days;
        if (diffDateDays > 0) return diffDateDays;
    startDate= new DateTime(year:date.Year-1,month:3,day:14); //14 March of previous year
    return (date- startDate).Days;
    }
```